# Movieclip to spawn in in a set perimeter

Tags: 2d, actionscript-3, random, spawning

I like to make a movieclip randomly spawn in a set area. But theres a little more to it, usually you'd have something like the X pos set to something like 250 (say the centre) and the Y pos set to be `math.random` but it won't work for how I'd like it.

I'm making a First Person Shooter and want the `Enemy movieclip` to spawn off stage but from the Top, Bottom, Left and Right of the stage as shown in the quick annotated image below.
[image: Annotated image]

Is this possible to be done? If so how could I achive this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you making a 2D first person shooter?  Why won't `math.random` work for how you'd like it?

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch, Yes it is a 2D FPS, but `math.random` wont work because I want the spawn area to be all around the stage about 20px out from the edges. If I was to do `X = math.random` and `Y = math.random` it would spawn them in the viewable area of the stage, but I want it to spawn outside of that.

Comment: I'm not sure FPS or "first person" means what you think it means.  Answer incoming, in any case.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch, Ah yes you do have a good point there, it essentially is third person shooter because it's top down.

Answer (score 1):

You can still trivially use `math.random`.  You just need to perform a little algebra.

If you have a 20 unit area on either side of some arbitrarily-sized area, you have 40 units in total split into two parts.  You can take a random number number and scale it to those 40 units and then place it appropriately whether that number is `<20` or `>=20`.

For instance:

```
spawnRandom():
 // get X in the 40 units of space legal to spawn in
 X = math.random() * 40

 // offset X to account for the middle area it can't be in
 if X < 20:
  X = -stage.width/2 - X
 else
  X = stage.width/2 + (X - 20)

 // same for Y

 return position(X, Y)
```

You now have a position that is linearly distributed across the legal areas while ignoring the center rectangle.

Comment: This does look like it will work! I shall implement it into the game now.